# Python Plotly image how to save image to a iobuffer and read it back

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

Python Matplotlib image is saved like :

```
img = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(img, format='png')
img.seek(0)
encoded = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())
```

but for plotly image the same code showing error like:

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'figure'
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

io.BytesIO has a function write().

```
img = io.BytesIO()
fig_svg = fig.to_image(format="svg") # kaleido library
img.write(fig_svg)
img.seek(0)
```